# Calling postgres command like pg_restore or pg_dump form sql file

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to run postgres command like pg_restore or pg_dump in sql files.

I have few insert statement and after that I would like to run pg_dump after that in same sql file.

Command to run pg_dump is

```
pg_dump -p5444 -U"username" -Fc -hhost-name  -d Database_name -t TABLENAME > location\abcd5.dump
```

How can I run the same with in sql file?

The machine I am using is unix.

Comment: You can't. `pg_dump` is not a SQL statement, it's a program that needs to be invoked through the means of the operating system (e.g. a shell script or a batch file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to achieve what you want, but it is not possible to do it the way you want.

Use a file you can run in your shell, for example bash (.sh) since you're on a Unix system.

In that file you can run your sql file with [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) and pg_dump command afterwards.

The shell file could look something like this:

```
psql -p <port> -U <username> -h <host-name> -d <database-name> <sql-file>
pg_dump -p5444 -U "username" -Fc -hhost-name  -d Database_name -t TABLENAME > location\abcd5.dump
```